# What PHP frameworks can I use to talk to gTalk?

Tags: php, google-talk

I want to connect to gTalk using PHP. How might I achieve this? What frameworks or SDKs are available?

Comment: any full featured framework or none at all http://code.google.com/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look on this [article](http://www.thedeveloperday.com/googletalk-integration-with-php/) or into [this](http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/) library
. Gtalk is classic XMPP protocol chat

Answer (score 3):

For example:

http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/

Not sure, if this is the right thing, too... but give it a shot: http://code.google.com/p/jaxl/